# Multiple Rows into a Single one SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a solution for the next example:

[image: Example]

What I would like to have is:

```
Check Type | Date       | Retailer | Value                    | Count

Duplicated | 2017-05-01 | SAMCO1   | 4742,4749,4853,6781,7658 | 5

Duplicated | 2017-05-02 | SAMCO1   | 4742,4749,4853,6781,7658 | 5
```

Comment: And what might your logic be?

Comment: SELECT MMC.CheckType,    
   PR.ModifiedDate,    
   MMC.RetailerID  ,
   AttributeValue,
   COUNT(*) AS MissingCount    
FROM MissingMappingCheck MMC  
INNER JOIN LastProcessRun  PR ON PR.ProcessRunID = MMC.ProcessRunId    
GROUP BY MMC.CheckType,    
    PR.ModifiedDate, MMC.RetailerID,   AttributeValue
ORDER BY MMC.CheckType, MMC.RetailerID  ,
    PR.ModifiedDate              this is the code that I am using

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      MMC.CheckType
    , PR.ModifiedDate
    , MMC.RetailerID
    , AttributeValue
    , COUNT(*) as MissingCount
  from MissingMappingCheck MMC
    inner join LastProcessRun PR 
      on PR.ProcessRunID = MMC.ProcessRunId
  group by 
      MMC.CheckType
    , PR.ModifiedDate
    , MMC.RetailerID
    , AttributeValue
)
select 
    CheckType
  , ModifiedDate
  , RetailerId
  , AttributeValues = stuff((
      select ','+i.AttributeValue 
      from cte as i
      where i.CheckType = t.CheckType
        and i.ModifiedDate = t.ModifiedDate
        and i.RetailerId = t.RetailerId
      order by i.AttributeValue
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
      ,1,1,'')
  , MissingCount = sum(MissingCount)
from cte t
group by CheckType, ModifiedDate, RetailerId
order by 
    CheckType
  , RetailerID
  , ModifiedDate
```